# How to determine epoch hyperparameter from grid search result

Tags: r, deep-learning, h2o, grid-search, hyperparameters

I have run a grid search, with epochs as one of the hyper parameters. Now after choosing the best model, how can I determine which epoch was chosen for this particular model?

Below is the summary of the model
    Model Details:
    ==============

```
H2OBinomialModel: deeplearning
Model ID:  dl_grid_model_19 
Status of Neuron Layers: predicting Churn, 2-class classification, bernoulli distribution, CrossEntropy loss, 4,226 weights/biases, 44.1 KB, 47,520 training samples, mini-batch size 1
  layer units             type dropout       l1       l2 mean_rate rate_rms momentum mean_weight weight_rms
1     1    30            Input  0.00 %                                                                     
2     2    32 RectifierDropout 20.00 % 0.000010 0.000010  0.009995 0.000000 0.501901   -0.011006   0.210611
3     3    32 RectifierDropout 20.00 % 0.000010 0.000010  0.009995 0.000000 0.501901   -0.035854   0.191687
4     4    32 RectifierDropout 20.00 % 0.000010 0.000010  0.009995 0.000000 0.501901   -0.029072   0.185352
5     5    32 RectifierDropout 20.00 % 0.000010 0.000010  0.009995 0.000000 0.501901   -0.057359   0.186863
6     6     2          Softmax         0.000010 0.000010  0.009995 0.000000 0.501901    0.122655   0.406789
  mean_bias bias_rms
1                   
2  0.401924 0.136989
3  0.938406 0.041128
4  0.950918 0.043826
5  0.915588 0.060796
6  0.019925 0.175195


H2OBinomialMetrics: deeplearning
** Reported on training data. **
** Metrics reported on full training frame **

MSE:  0.1946901
RMSE:  0.441237
LogLoss:  0.5731371
Mean Per-Class Error:  0.194215
AUC:  0.8767996
Gini:  0.7535992

Confusion Matrix for F1-optimal threshold:
         No  Yes    Error       Rate
No     1755  614 0.259181  =614/2369
Yes     308 2075 0.129249  =308/2383
Totals 2063 2689 0.194024  =922/4752

Maximum Metrics: Maximum metrics at their respective thresholds
                        metric threshold    value idx
1                       max f1  0.216316 0.818218 266
2                       max f2  0.058723 0.889206 348
3                 max f0point5  0.306487 0.801744 216
4                 max accuracy  0.217122 0.805976 265
5                max precision  0.730797 1.000000   0
6                   max recall  0.006754 1.000000 398
7              max specificity  0.730797 1.000000   0
8             max absolute_mcc  0.216316 0.616944 266
9   max min_per_class_accuracy  0.257957 0.795636 242
10 max mean_per_class_accuracy  0.217122 0.805792 265

Gains/Lift Table: Extract with `h2o.gainsLift(<model>, <data>)` or `h2o.gainsLift(<model>, valid=<T/F>, xval=<T/F>)`
H2OBinomialMetrics: deeplearning
** Reported on validation data. **
** Metrics reported on full validation frame **

MSE:  0.1418929
RMSE:  0.3766867
LogLoss:  0.4374728
Mean Per-Class Error:  0.2603761
AUC:  0.8306744
Gini:  0.6613489

Confusion Matrix for F1-optimal threshold:
         No Yes    Error       Rate
No     1075 201 0.157524  =201/1276
Yes     162 284 0.363229   =162/446
Totals 1237 485 0.210801  =363/1722

Maximum Metrics: Maximum metrics at their respective thresholds
                        metric threshold    value idx
1                       max f1  0.323830 0.610097 183
2                       max f2  0.087110 0.740000 319
3                 max f0point5  0.514027 0.608666  94
4                 max accuracy  0.514027 0.800232  94
5                max precision  0.668538 0.875000  21
6                   max recall  0.011443 1.000000 389
7              max specificity  0.717464 0.999216   0
8             max absolute_mcc  0.323830 0.466764 183
9   max min_per_class_accuracy  0.229876 0.746082 238
10 max mean_per_class_accuracy  0.173814 0.753367 273

Gains/Lift Table: Extract with `h2o.gainsLift(<model>, <data>)` or `h2o.gainsLift(<model>, valid=<T/F>, xval=<T/F>)`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find out how many epochs a model used, the best way is to look at the score history. E.g. for a model `m`:

```
h2o.scoreHistory(m)
```

(Or for a graphical version, plot the model: `plot(m)` )

That may be too much information, so reduce it to just show epochs with:

```
h2o.scoreHistory(m)[,c("epochs")]
```

(I just noticed `h2o.scoreHistory(m)$epochs` will work, too.)

Show the epochs, of the final model that was returned, with:

```
last( h2o.scoreHistory(m)[,c("epochs")] )
```

By the way, if you had just printed the grid object you should have seen epochs as one of the columns, if it was one of your hyper-parameters.

**Answering the question you didn't ask:** take a look at early stopping, which will free you from having to try to guess in advance how many epochs you need, and therefore also save you a hyper-parameter in your grid searches.

You could also simply make the model with the highest epoch value you are considering, and look in the score history to get the scores at each of the other epoch values you were interested in.